# How to fix file not being able to be read in JavaFX

Tags: java, file, javafx, runtime-error

I'm working on a program using Java FX that needs to be able to write and then read a file. Writing my file works perfectly fine when I press the write button in my GUI, however, when I try to read from that file and display the contents in the GUI's text area, it throws my catch exception. I know there is an easier way to display the text, but I need to do it similar to this way in order to format how the various elements show up in the text area.

Thank you!

```
@FXML
private void read(ActionEvent event) 
{

    ta.clear();
    ta.setText("Name\tDescription\tPrice\t\tCopies\tTotal");
    try
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(myfile);

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            String s=input.next();                
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(s);
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            String n1=sc.nextLine();
            String d1=sc.nextLine();
            double pr1=sc.nextDouble();
            double cop1=sc.nextDouble();
            double total=pr1*cop1;

            ta.appendText(n1+"\t\t"+d1+"\t\t"+pr1+"\t\t"+cop1+"\n"+total);                                                      
        }
        input.close();

    }
     catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in reading the file...");
    }

}
```

I expect the contents of myfile to be displayed in text area "ta" in my GUI.

Comment: First of all try to print exception and hand out _what exactly_ goes wrong.

Comment: The exception is likely coming from reading the file, and nothing to do with JavaFX. Try printing out the exception stacktrace like so to debug why it is throwing the exception: ``` catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Error in reading the file..., " + e.printStackTrace()); }
```

Comment: You're probably going to think this is silly, but I didn't know how to do that as we were never taught, so I looked it up, and the information it gave me allowed me to fix it, so thank you haha.